# Change legend size in plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to change the legend size in plotly for R? I have not come across this option. I have looked at the docs on legends, https://plot.ly/r/legend/, but it does not mention this.

Comment: Will be changing the font size enough?

Comment: No. The scale and position will need to changed. But thank you.

Comment: See https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-legend for possible options

Comment: Which option are you referring to? I don't see anything pertaining to scaling the size of the legend.

Comment: I don't think changing the size is possible. The only things you could do are related to positioning, font size and some other aesthetic features that do not affect the overall size of the legend.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `layout(legend = list(font = list(size(30))))`:

```
plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = as.character(mtcars$cyl), 
        y = mtcars$mpg, type = "box", color = as.character(mtcars$cyl)) %>%
    layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = list(font = list(size = 30)))
```

Comment: using (font = list(size(30))) increases the font but not the actual legend box

Comment: If using `size(30)` throws an error, try `size = 30` instead.

Answer (score 12):

While working with legends, there are two pieces to configure.

1. Legend title (***legend_title*** parameter)
2. Actual legend (***legend*** parameter)

Let's say you already have a fig(it can be mostly any plot), to that add below line with parameters as you wish, in separate dictionaries.

```
fig.update_layout(legend = dict(font = dict(family = "Courier", size = 50, color = "black")),
                  legend_title = dict(font = dict(family = "Courier", size = 30, color = "blue")))
```

This way you will have more control over two thing.

Comment: OP asked about the programming language R. Your response does not contain any R code.

Comment: @bcstryker properties suppose to be the same

Comment: @Sesha What about symbol size as, in your example, this only changes font size?