# Is it possible to change the size of the legend box in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

[image: example of legend box in plotly]

In my code, when I change the font size with a smaller value, the legend box does not adapt to the new size. Do you know what attribute I can add to be able to adjust the box size?

The library used is Plotly.

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, height=500, width=1000, title_text="Analysis of Latency",
                  legend=dict(
                      x=0, y=1,traceorder="normal",font=dict(size=10),bgcolor="WhiteSmoke")
```

[image]

Comment: [Change legend size in plotly chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245004/change-legend-size-in-plotly-chart) I find this answer to be very helpful

Comment: The answer you mentioned follow the same code that I already have: legend=dict(font=dict(size=10)) (instead of a dictionary, in R it is a list). However, this approach only change the font size inside the legend box. But the dimensions of the legend box itself are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing a few comments on various questions suggesting that this can't be done, there seems to be an approach that works pretty nicely.

```
legend.sizes = seq(80, 160, 20)
ax = list(zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE)
mk = list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area")

p.map = plot_geo(DF, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_markers(x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~Group, size = ~Value, marker = mk) %>%
  layout(geo = list(scope = 'usa'))

p.legend = plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(x = 1, y = legend.sizes, size = legend.sizes, showlegend = F, marker = mk) %>%
  layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE))

subplot(p.legend, p.map, widths = c(0.1, 0.9))
```