# Increase size of color icons in ggplotly legend

Tags: ggplot2, ggplotly

I have the following ggplotly chart. How can I increase the size of the legend icons in `ggplotly`? The icons appear very thin in `ggplotly` compared to my static `ggplot`

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 
1648771200, 1651363200, 1654041600, 1656633600, 1659312000, 1661990400
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Variable = c("Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", 
"Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", "Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", 
"Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", "Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", 
"Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", "Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", 
"Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)", "Zinc concentrate production volume (tons)"
), Value = c(0.176935645322967, 1.09984311986, 0.696173307906093, 
-0.757110090664708, -2.39009319660863, -0.924763914389984, -0.962968019123352, 
-1.79683715589855, 0.0254350069494616), Color = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L), levels = c("#0a5d00", "#0eff00", 
"#ece75f", "#FFBF00", "#ff0000", "#7b0000"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Label = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L), levels = c("> 2 Standard Deviations from mean", "1 to 2 Standard Deviations from mean", 
"0 to 1 Standard Deviations from mean", "0 to -1 Standard Deviations from mean", 
"-1 to -2 Standard Deviations from mean", "> -2 Standard Deviations from mean"
), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

dat %>% {
    ggplot(.,aes(Date, Variable, fill = Label)) +
      geom_tile(col = 'white') +
      theme_light() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = levels(as.factor(.$Color)),
                        breaks = levels(as.factor(.$Label))) +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
} %>% 
  ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Label')) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(xanchor = "left", y = -.2, x = -.2, orientation = "h",
                       title = list(text = "")))
```

[image]

I would like my icons to appear more like this as they are in a static ggplot2

[image]

Comment: is this post helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245004/change-legend-size-in-plotly-chart

Comment: @Mike that solution is to increase the size of the text in the legend and not the icons in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

I found `itemwidth` to increase the width, and I found that `itemsymbol="constant"` slightly increases the height.

```r
library(plotly)

dat %>% {
  ggplot(.,aes(Date, Variable, fill = Label)) +
    geom_tile(col = 'white') +
    theme_light() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = levels(as.factor(.$Color)),
                      breaks = levels(as.factor(.$Label))) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
} %>% 
  ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Label')) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      xanchor = "left", y = -.2, x = -0.3, orientation = "v",
      title = list(text = ""), 
      itemsymbol = "constant", itemwidth=100
    )
  )
```

---

## Edit

Actually `itemsymbol` does not exist... There's `itemsizing`.

To get squares as legend items use a "true" plotly and not a ggplotly.